# Query Error:Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a variable

```
DECLARE @CustomerName NVARCHAR(50);
```

I would like to take the results of the query below and concat it into the variable that I can use to return the values

```
SELECT Firstname, Lastname FROM CustomerData
```

100 Returned Records

The following query gives me the error in the subject

```
  DECLARE @CustomerName nvarchar(50);
  SELECT @CustomerName = (SELECT Firstname, Lastname FROM CustomerData)
  SELECT @CustomerName AS 'Customer Name';
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You've tagged `mysql` and `tsql`, did you maybe mean `sql-server`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scalar variable can only be bound to a single value. For example:

```
declare @CustomerName nvarchar(50);
select top 1 @CustomerName = Firstname + ' ' + Lastname from CustomerData;
```

If you have more than one row, a scalar variable probably won't do what you want.

[Example SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5ded/1)

Comment: Sorry, I skipped the declare. Also I'm assuming there's only 1 row. If there's more you need some way to restrict things, or you need to use a table variable.

Comment: well its not valid for mysql at least. not sure if its mysql though so its valid. my bad

Comment: He's using SQL Server Management Studio, it's not mysql

Comment: hes using tsql.. or well thats what was said on my post.. sigh.. i dislike it when theres stuff tagged that doesn't reflect the actual situation

Comment: So what do I do if I have more then one result?

Comment: It all depends what you're trying to achieve. Why can't you return a result set to your client and let it do the formatting?

Comment: @GhostDZ9 the only way to get more results into one variable in tsql is to use stuff.. here is an example. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5ded/7

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a colon before the equals to do assignment to your user defined variable

## MySQL

```
SET @CustomerName := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Firstname, ' ', Lastname)) FROM CustomerData);
SELECT @CustomerName AS 'Customer Name';
```

concat the names together because you can only assign one value to the variable

you can use SELECT INTO if you prefer it that way.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Firstname, ' ', Lastname)) INTO @CustomerName FROM CustomerData;
```

## T-SQL

```
DECLARE @CustomerName nvarchar(50);
SELECT @CustomerName = Firstname + ' ' + Lastname FROM customerdata;
SELECT @CustomerName;
```

this assumes you have only one name if you have more you should either add top 1 (as Lawrence did in his answer) or you can stuff it all in one string like so.

```
SELECT @CustomerName = (
  SELECT 
    stuff(
        (
        select cast(',' as varchar(max)) + c.firstname + ' ' + c.lastname
        from customerdata c

        order by c.firstname
        for xml path('')
        ), 1, 1, ''
    ) AS Customers
);
```

Comment: @GhostDZ9 use SET for assigning the variable... or SELECT INTO i'll edit my post

Comment: I get the following result based on what you have suggested:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ':'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @GhostDZ9 are you using mysql?

Comment: No I believe its T-SQL

Comment: @GhostDZ9 well then why do you have mysql tagged? its different for each language.

Answer (score 0):

Use concat function to join the firstname and lastname as below...

```
-- for mysql
SELECT @CustomerName = (SELECT concat(Firstname,' ',Lastname) AS Name FROM CustomerData)

-- for sql-server
SELECT @CustomerName = (SELECT Firstname + ' ' + Lastname AS Name FROM CustomerData)
```

Comment: yup beat ya to it!  :)

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Modified answer to put query for both mysql and sql-server... concat function is added in sql-server 2012 onward... before that you need to use plus sign "+"